# Should I be able to retract a reopen vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen, retracted-close-votes

Earlier today I voted to reopen a question, but on further consideration decided that it should remain closed.  Since we can now retract close votes, I tried to retract the reopen vote by clicking on the "reopen" link, but instead I just got the "vote to reopen?" dialogue.  (I didn't try clicking "ok"; I assume that had I done so I would have been told I've already voted.)

Is this expected behavior -- we can retract close votes but not reopen votes?

Comment: Oh wow.  I wonder why that didn't show up in the similar-questions dropdown?  Sorry.

Comment: Probably means this is a good sign post for the future :)